# Calculting interest on investment

Tags: economics

Given an investment of 9550000 USD I want to know what the value of this investment is after one year if I have to pay 10% of interest per year.

According to my understanding, that would be 90% of the investment which equals to 8595000 USD.

According to the solutions, however, it is  8681818 USD.

I can see that this is around 91% of the initial investment. Which formula for the calculation of interests, however, is used to arrive at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You discount the investment. That means you divide it by $(1+i)=(1+0.1)=1.1$

$C_0=9,550,000\cdot \frac1{1.1}=...$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: You´re welcome. And a happy new year, now or in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to phrase your question carefully.  It looks like you are looking for the amount you would have to invest today to have $9550000$ in one year if the interest rate is $10\%$, which is not what you asked.  If $P$ is the principal you invest today, after one year you have $1.1P$.  We want 
$$1.1P=9550000\\P=\frac{9550000}{1.1}=8681818$$
Note that dividing by $1.1$ is not the same as multiplying by $0.9$